# Draw Something 2 - how to scroll the colour palette?

Tags: draw-something

Alcatel OneTouch 983, Android 2.3.7

I needed more colours, so I picked up the free Despicable Me 2 colour set from the shop.  The five new colours have appeared at the beginning of the palette; however, two of the five basic colours have been pushed off the screen.

So now I have 10 colours, as confirmed on the shop screen.  However, I can only access 8 of them.  I imagined that swiping my finger across the palette would scroll it, but it doesn't (in either direction).

How am I supposed to get at my blue and green now?  Help me please!

Comment: Since I originally posted this I discovered that there's a bug in the app's screen size detection, and so the UI was disappearing off the screen.  And this is what had happened to two of my colours.

So I guess the answer is "wait for the developer to fix the bug".  Unless it has been fixed since I last played it....

Answer (score -1):

If you tap the arrow under the palette, you will see the rest of your colours.

Comment: Already tried that - didn't work.